# Bot status Discord.js 14.6.0

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

how can I get bot status (discord.js 14.6.0)? At the bottom, I added my code - please bear with us, because this is my first JS project.

`

```
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');

const commands = [
  {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Replies with Pong!',
  },
];

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken("MY-TOKEN");

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

    await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands("CLIENT-ID"), { body: commands });

    console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

  if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
    await interaction.reply('Pong!');
  }
});

client.login("MY-TOKEN");
```

`

I tried to work on all that are on the internet, but nothing works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How I can add bot status in my bot? (discord.js 14.6.0)

Answer (score -1):

**already coded**

```js
 const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');

const commands = [
  {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Replies with Pong!',
  },
];

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken("MY-TOKEN");

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

    await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands("CLIENT-ID"), { body: commands });

    console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, ActivityType } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.on('ready', () => {
client.user.setActivity(`discord.js v14 `, {type: ActivityType.Playing});
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

  if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
    await interaction.reply('Pong!');
  }
});

client.login("MY-TOKEN");
```